# Has the Federal Republic of Germany ever refused diplomatic credentials for foreign ambassadors?

Tags: germany, diplomacy

The proposal of Douglas Macgregor as [US ambassador for Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Macgregor#U.S._Ambassador_to_Germany_nomination) has been criticized in Germany and it has been suggested that the Germany government should simply refuse his [diplomatic credentials](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akkreditierung_(Diplomatie)). According to [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akkreditierung_(Diplomatie))  the first step of being accepted as an ambassador to a foreign state is to discreetly ask the foreign state if the ambassador would be accepted, which must be agreed to formally and can be *refused without giving any reasons*.

Though this is unlikely for political reasons to happen for a proposed US ambassador to Germany - do we know if the Federal Republic of Germany has ever done this?

Comment: Today I read a comment on the problem the other way around (https://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/ausland/warum-laesst-polen-den-neuen-deutschen-botschafter-warten-16920931.html, paywall). The current proposed ambassador of Germany in Poland waits for the Agrément already for 13 weeks. A few other cases of the last years are named: 2013 the Germany -> Tansania (Margit Hellwig-Bötte), Agrément denied; 2015 France -> Holy See (Laurent Stefanini), Agrément did not come over months, so that another candidate were proposed; Russia -> Ukraine (Michail Babitsch), Agrément denied.

Comment: So it seems to be seldom, but it happens and also happens that it gets publicly known.